# HTML 5 File API. Upload multiple files and specify custom files order before upload to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, file-upload, fileapi

I have the following issue. I can upload multiple files to the server, but they are uploaded only in the order which was set when I selected this files (images for example). I would like before uploading to the server specify my own order. For example, I selected three images:
Image A
Image B
Image C
if I submit form they will upload in this order. But I want they would upload in order like:
Image C
Image A
Image B

I can use jQuery UI sortable method but it doesn't help. I know that files need to be deleted from HTTP headers and uploaded to there in new order, but how to do that...
Here you can see what example (upload and dragging images):

```
    $(function(){
$('#images').change(function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    filesTest = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function() {
            return function(event) {
                $('#uploadedImages').append('<li><img src="' + event.target.result + '" width="100"/></li>');
            };
        })(file);

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});

$('#uploadedImages').sortable();
$('#uploadedImages').disableSelection(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36ZwA

Any suggestions will be appriciated

Comment: files=[].slice.call(files).sort(function ...)

Comment: I reordered files in FileList with Array.prorotype.splice method. But it didn't help me:( When I submit form on server side I receive files in start order anyway

Comment: submit the form? FileReader doesn't make sense if you're not using ajax to upload the files... if you must use a form, append to the form once per file via FormData from  the sorted files list, then remove the bulky file input, then submit.